# How to redirect an entire range/block of IP addresses with PHP?

Tags: php, redirect, ip

I'm using the following snippet to redirect an array of IP addresses. I was wondering how I would go about adding an entire range/block of IP addresses to my dissallowed array...

```
<?php // Let's redirect certain IP addresses to a "Page Not Found"
$disallowed = array("76.105.99.106");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

if(in_array($ip, $disallowed)) {
 header("Location: http://google.com");
 exit;
}
?>
```

I tried using "76.105.99.*", "76.105.99", "76.105.99.0-76.105.99.255" without any luck.

I need to use PHP rather than mod_rewrite and .htaccess for other reasons.

Comment: I would think you'd need to re-engineer your comparison code to understand the abbreviation you are going to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `substr` function:

```
$ip = '76.105.99.';
if (substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, strlen($ip)) === $ip) {
    // deny access
}
```

Comment: sir what if the format of the ip range is 76.105.99.0/127?

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example of how you could check a particular network/mask combination:

```
$network=ip2long("76.105.99.0");
$mask=ip2long("255.255.255.0");
$remote=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (($remote & $mask)==$network)
{
    header("Location: http://example.com");
    exit;
}
```

This is better than using a string based match as you can test other masks that align within an octet, e.g. a /20 block of IPs

Comment: You did something wrong, or made an assumption which wasn't valid.

Comment: My code is here:
    `<?php
    $network=ip2long("124.195.223.98");
    $mask=ip2long("255.255.255.0");
    $remote=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    
    if ((($remote & $mask) == $network)){
       echo "match";
    }else{
       echo "No match";
    }
    ?>`
It always say no match.
Note: My IP is 124.195.223.99

Comment: The final octet of your network address is invalid and should be zero for the mask you've given

Comment: Which mask should I use if the final octet is 98? Actually the IP range starts from 98 and ends with 125.

Comment: This technique is only valid for matching against CIDR style  netblocks. For your purposes you could simply convert the start and end of your range to longs and see if the ip you want to test is in that range.

Answer (score 3):

You can approach the problem in a different way.

If you want to ban 76.105.99.* you could do:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "76.105.99.")!==FALSE)
{
    header ('Location: http://google.com');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Who exactly are you interested in blocking?  You can use PHP or apache to block (or allow) a bunch of specific IP addresses.

If you are interested in blocking people from an entire country for example, then there are tools that give you the IP addresses you need to block.  Unfortunately, it's not as simple as just specifying a range.

Check out http://www.blockacountry.com/ which generates a bunch of ip addresses you can stick in your .htaccess to block whole countries.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to have a test to see if a particular address lives inside a particular address range as defined by CIDR

So for instance, you need to be able to say

is 192.168.1.5

inside

192.168.1.0/24

That function is easy to write, assuming you have some basic tools to do CIDR work.

Assuming you are on a 32bit system, this class http://snipplr.com/view/15557/cidr-class-for-ipv4/
Pay attention to the IPisWithinCIDR function

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do this in apache(or any other server)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll need to create a for loop to add each IP address (within the range) to your array.

pseudo code

```
for i = 0 to 255
    disallowed[i] = "76.105.99." + i
next
```

Comment: Doing a for loop seems to be a very sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$blocked_ip_range_array = array('109.237.108.0','109.238.0.0');
for($i=0;$i<count($blocked_ip_range_array);$i++){
    $network=ip2long($blocked_ip_range_array[$i]);
    $blipr = explode(".",$blocked_ip_range_array[$i]);
    if($blipr[2]=='0'){
        $mask=ip2long("255.255.0.0");
    }
    else{
        $mask=ip2long("255.255.255.0");
    }
    $remote=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if (($remote & $mask)==$network)
    {
        header("Location: http://xurcun.info");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Below is a URL showing something rather similar to what Mr. Dixon and Ameer are discussing:
http://www.blackdog.ie/blog/blocking-ip-ranges-with-php/

Hope this helps.

Respectfully,
Wil